# MySQL daemon keeps terminating unexpectedly

Tags: mysql

The MySQL daemon on my CentOS server keeps crashing, i got the logs from /var/logs/mysqld but still i am not sure how to fix this:

```
121114 16:22:56 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended                                                                                                 
121114 21:55:11 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql                                                                                             
121114 21:55:11 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.                                                                                                                            
121114 21:55:11 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled                                                                                                                        
121114 21:55:11 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins                                                                                                              
121114 21:55:11 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3                                                                                                                          
121114 21:55:11 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO                                                                                                                                    
121114 21:55:11 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M                                                                                                                   
121114 21:55:11 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool                                                                                                                   
121114 21:55:11 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.                                                                                                               
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match                                                                                                                    
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!                                                                                                                               
121114 21:55:11  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!                                                                                                                     
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.                                                                                                                                                  
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...                                                                                                                     
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite                                                                                                           
InnoDB: buffer...                                                                                                                                                                 
121114 21:55:12  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start                                                                                                              
121114 21:55:13 InnoDB: 1.1.6 started; log sequence number 77177262                                                                                                               
121114 21:55:13 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events                                                                                                                           
121114 21:55:13 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.                                                                                                                
Version: '5.5.12'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi                                                                          
121115 00:19:44 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0                                                                                                                    
121115 00:19:44 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted                                                                                                                                      
121115  0:19:47 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.                                                                                                                            
121115  0:19:47 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled                                                                                                                        
121115  0:19:47 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins                                                                                                              
121115  0:19:47 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3                                                                                                                          
121115  0:19:47 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO                                                                                                                                    
121115  0:19:47 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M                                                                                                                   
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12                                                                                                                                    
121115  0:19:47 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool                                                                                                                   
121115  0:19:47 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool                                                                                                   
121115  0:19:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.                                                                                                             
121115  0:19:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.                                                                                                  
121115  0:19:47 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB                                                                                                                
121115  0:19:47 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it's crashing, but being restarted. Do you have any cronjobs running at around that time?

Comment: Of course, then I read the rest of the log. Can you give your specs on the centos machine (RAM) and what other processes you run on it (apache/php/etc)? 128MB innodb buffer pool should not be causing a memory issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually MySQL crashing.

It's running...

```
121114 21:55:13 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.                                                                                                                
Version: '5.5.12'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
```

...and then it's not running...

```
121115 00:19:44 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
```

If MySQL were crashing, you would almost certainly see messages between those two entries.

This, also, is not MySQL crashing:

```
121115  0:19:47 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M                                                                                                                   
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12                                                                                                                                    
121115  0:19:47 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool                                                                                                                   
121115  0:19:47 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
```

This is MySQL trying to restart after being killed, but unable to restart because your system doesn't have enough available memory at that moment.

See [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25077/mysql-innodb-crash-post-mortem/25083) and 
[this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25165) for an explanation of what's happening... you should find entries in /var/log/messages indicating that the kernel is deliberately killing mysqld due to an overall shortage of system memory... most likely caused by your web server making heavy demands for memory.