# Mysql craches ! InnoDB

Tags: mysql

The full mysql error log, the VPS craches almost every day! I need to add more info but I can't so this is the only info I have :

```
131117 20:08:47 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131117 20:08:47 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131117 20:08:47 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131117 20:08:47 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
131117 20:08:47 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(135987200 bytes) failed; errno 12
131117 20:08:47 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131117 20:08:47 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
131117 20:08:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
131117 20:08:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
131117 20:08:47 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
131117 20:08:47 [ERROR] Aborting

131117 20:08:47 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

131117 21:03:18 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131117 21:03:18 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131117 21:03:18 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131117 21:03:18 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
131117 21:03:18 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131117 21:03:18 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131117 21:03:18 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
131117 21:03:18  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
131117 21:03:18  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
131117 21:03:19 InnoDB: 5.5.32 started; log sequence number 46233374
131117 21:03:19 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
131117 21:03:19 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
131117 21:03:19 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
131117 21:03:19 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
131117 21:03:19 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
131117 21:03:20 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './zadmin_status/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
131117 21:03:20 [Warning] Checking table:   './zadmin_status/wp_options'
131117 21:03:21 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './zadmin_status/wp_postmeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
131117 21:03:21 [Warning] Checking table:   './zadmin_status/wp_postmeta'
131117 21:03:21 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './zadmin_status/wp_posts' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
131117 21:03:21 [Warning] Checking table:   './zadmin_status/wp_posts'
131117 21:03:21 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './zadmin_status/wp_quick_chat_users' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
131117 21:03:21 [Warning] Checking table:   './zadmin_status/wp_quick_chat_users'
131117 21:03:21 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './zadmin_status/wp_term_relationships' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
131117 21:03:21 [Warning] Checking table:   './zadmin_status/wp_term_relationships'
131117 21:03:21 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './zadmin_status/wp_term_taxonomy' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
131117 21:03:21 [Warning] Checking table:   './zadmin_status/wp_term_taxonomy'
131117 21:03:21 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './zadmin_status/wp_usermeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
131117 21:03:21 [Warning] Checking table:   './zadmin_status/wp_usermeta'
131117 21:03:21 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './zpanel_core/x_bandwidth' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
131117 21:03:21 [Warning] Checking table:   './zpanel_core/x_bandwidth'
131117 21:03:21 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './zpanel_core/x_mysql_databases' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
131117 21:03:21 [Warning] Checking table:   './zpanel_core/x_mysql_databases'
131117 21:03:21 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './zpanel_proftpd/ftpuser' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
131117 21:03:21 [Warning] Checking table:   './zpanel_proftpd/ftpuser'
```

Please help me to solve that problem. Thanks ! I have no info anymore but it requests me to add more. I cannot add anymore because this is all I know.

Comment: The message `InnoDB: mmap(135987200 bytes) failed; errno 12` looks like where the problems start. That's what I would start Googling for. Perhaps this helps: [Amazon EC2, mysql aborting start because InnoDB: mmap (x bytes) failed; errno 12](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10284532)

Comment: Your server does not have enough memory to run MySQL and whatever else you are running.  The actual crash is not shown in the log file you posted; the actual crash is occurring prior to this.  What you've posted is MySQL trying to restart itself but being unable to because the system has insufficient memory, see [InnoDB Crash Post Mortem](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25077) and [Intermittent Crashes .. Cannot Allocate Memory for the InnoDB Buffer Pool](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25165).