# How database buffer pool work?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

For example we have 2 scenarios:

Scenario 1:-
             We have very small `buffer pool size` of 100MB. My query data is 500MB. Does the         system keep 500MB query data in RAM such that a new query will read from RAM?

Scenario 2:-
           `Buffer pool size` is 1GB. In this situation will the system always keep 1GB free (in RAM) for MySQL query processing. Can the 1GB be used by other processes?

Answer (score 1):

The amount of memory specified in `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is allocated when the MySQL Server daemon starts up, and if the system doesn't have that much memory free at that moment, MySQL won't start.

The amount of memory you specify is what the buffer pool gets, and it neither grows nor shrinks.

InnoDB reads pages from disk into the pool as they are needed for queries, and the data remains in the pool for future queries until the least-recently-used data is eventually evicted by different data, when the pool is out of space... but the allocated memory is not available for any other process.

MySQL will request additional memory from the system for various other buffers needed by individual threads, but when the buffer pool itself is exhausted for space, no additional memory will be used for storing cached table pages.  Anything that doesn't fit into the buffer pool will not persist in memory for subsequent access.

Ideally MySQL runs on its own hardware.  An environment where MySQL is competing with other processes for memory is not optimum.  This is particularly true with a web server like Apache on the same machine, which [commonly causes problems under load](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25077), because both the web server and the database are making demands for memory at the same time.