# Does mysql "lock" (no other process can take from it) the memory allocated to it?

Tags: mysql, memory

I have a 64GB memory machine, and I set mysql buffer pool to be 40GB. So MySQL is using up to 40G memory while it's running.

I kicked off a java application that requires more than 20GB memory, so the java application starts to consume more and more memory and eventually the total 64G memory is not enough for both java and mysql.

Now, the interesting problem shows: mysql crashed (see graph [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fxlgvqmf4ybnpvu/Screenshot%202015-11-01%2014.53.26.png?dl=0)). But to my understand, shouldn't mysql stays the same, and instead Java crashes? Since the 40G memory is already allocated to mysql, the java application shouldn't take it away right?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check kernel log, you should see OoM Killed messages.. Kernel will usually kill the largest offender which is MySQL in ourcase.

Comment: Indeed.  Usually mysql is not "crashing" but rather is being killed. http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25083/11651 When this happens, it will try to restart itself, and usually will fail because all of the configured memory for the InnoDB buffer pool is allocated at startup, which won't work if that much memory is not available.

Comment: Just to extend on "it will try to restart itself"-->  mysqld will be killed and mysqld_safe the wrapper script will attempt to start the mysqld.

Comment: Agreed.  Oversimplification on my part.

Comment: Simple and clear. That makes sense. I did find the message in the kernal log. Thank you.

Comment: So -- decrease `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.