# Internal MariaDB error code: 1927 ('Connection was killed')

Tags: mariadb, galera, multi-master, mariadb-10.1

Edit: filed a bug report at https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14493

Mariadb nodes freeze occasionally with the following error in the logs, any clues?

(drupal app, db freezes on clearing application cache)

```
[Warning] WSREP: Failed to apply app buffer: seqno: 903792, status: 1
Nov 23 21:42:55 websrv4 mysqld[1725]: #011 at 
galera/src/trx_handle.cpp:apply():351
Nov 23 21:42:55 websrv4 mysqld[1725]: Retrying 2th time
Nov 23 21:42:55 websrv4 mysqld[1725]: 2017-11-23 21:42:55 140081879742208 
[Warning] WSREP: BF applier failed to open_and_lock_tables: 1927, fatal: 0 
wsrep = (exec_mode: 1 conflict_state: 5 seqno: 903792)
Nov 23 21:42:55 websrv4 mysqld[1725]: 2017-11-23 21:42:55 140081879742208 
[ERROR] Slave SQL: Error executing row event: 'Connection was killed', 
Internal MariaDB error code: 1927
```

Comment: Just checking, is your application adhering to the [Galera limitations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations/) such as the requirement that all tables *must* have an explicit primary key? From experience, Galera will die if you have a table without a primary key, and then delete data from it. "Clearing application cache" sounds like something that could be deleting rows.

Comment: its drupal so probably yes. and only under load, and only sometimes (almost daily). cache is cleared anyway every 3 hours or less.

Comment: Is your application configured to access more than one DB node, e.g. through a DB proxy (like MaxScale or ProxySQL)? If so, make sure to use a read-write splitter to avoid writing to more than one node, as this is [known for causing deadlocks](https://ghostaldev.com/2016/05/22/galera-gotcha-mysql-users/), as seemed to be the problem in your first crash log that you uploaded to the MariaDB Jira.

Comment: dbdemon, If you add your answer separately I'll mark it solved after a few days with no crashes.

Comment: So did you have any more crashes?

Comment: unfortunately yes, it was a bug in mariadb that is supposed to be fixed in 10.2.11, haven't checked yet, the workaround of disabling nagios also worked.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from the comments that your application is writing to more than one DB node. This is [known for causing deadlocks](https://ghostaldev.com/2016/05/22/galera-gotcha-mysql-users/), and this appears to be the underlying problem in your first crash log that you uploaded to the MariaDB Jira. If you're using a DB proxy (like MaxScale or ProxySQL), then make sure to use a [read-write splitter](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-enterprise/mariadb-maxscale-14/maxscale-readwrite-splitting-with-galera-cluster/) so you write to only one node, but read from all.